# How to you make such a seamless patterns in adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, tools

I came across some designs of a seamless patterns which look great, i wonder how to create such vector designs in illustrator? They are seamless and when i make something similar with a pattern tool in AI, the pattern i get is a single element which then applies as a swatch. After applying the pattern tool all the copies dissaper.

[image]

what i need is a similar design that fills the whole artboard, not only as a swatch. I mean, how to creat such a seamless artwork that will fit exactly the artboard, what will your technique be?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know how to fill the artboard with your pattern or do you want to learn how to make a seamless pattern like your bottom example? Can you [edit] your question to make it more clear?

Comment: @Luciano Yeah exactly to make a seamless pattern that will fit the size of the artboard (will be uploading the files to microstocks) so i want to have the seamless pattern to be the exact size like the artboard (not to fill the area with a pattern swatch) Sorry for the unclarity  it's kind of difficult to explain :) The wanted result is a seamless design similar to the one in the image above that will appear seamless on the artboard size.

Comment: Does the answer provided solve your problem? Is it any close? Please add a comment under it so the poster can improve the answer or mark it as accepted if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to set a pattern as an artboard background.

Make a rectangle shape filled with the pattern and covering the whole document. If you need this as a background, double click the layer to transform it to a *Template Layer*. This *template layer* will be locked and the name will be *italicized*.

[image]